# Why doesn't system() work when called in a loop with cd and rm commands?

Tags: command-line, permissions, scripts, c, cd-command

I started using Linux recently, so my program is just for learning. Having said that, here's my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {

FILE *fin;
char buf[200];

fin = fopen("provaMake.txt", "r");
if (fin==NULL) {
    fin = fopen("/home/giorgio/Desktop/provaMake.txt", "r");
    if (fin==NULL) {
        printf("finError\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

while(fgets(buf, 200, fin) != NULL) {

    system(buf);

}

fclose(fin);

}
```

And here's the `provaMake.txt` file:

```bash
cd /home/giorgio/Desktop/a
rm -f pippo.txt
cd /home/giorgio/Desktop
```

When I run it using:

```bash
$gcc provaMake.c -o provaMake.o
$./provaMake.o
```

It didn't delete pippo.txt (that's in the `a` directory inside `Desktop`).

Am I doing something wrong in code? I repeat that I'm trying to learn, so please explain this to me (or redirect me where can I learn).

Comment: commands don't begin with `$` - the shell invoked by `system` is likely treating them as empty variables

Comment: (1) `system()` runs a command through the default shell; type `$cd /home/giorgio/Desktop/a` and see what happens. Then type `echo "$cd /home/giorgio/Desktop/a"` to see what the shell understood. Then think why `$cd` disappeared. (2) And the `cd` commands would be no-operations anyway. Try to understand why.

Comment: One thing you should learn is to never use `system()`.

Comment: what do you suggest instead? @fkraiem

Comment: Try semicolons, https://stackoverflow.com/q/245600

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`system()` runs a command in a shell. That shell is a new [process](http://foldoc.org/process). It is a child process of your C program. **The `cd` command changes the current directory for the shell process in which it is run.** This is inherited by child processes of that shell. But it does not affect the current directory for parent processes.

You're calling `system()` three times. Each time, a shell process is started, it runs a command, and it ends. **`cd` in one call to `system()` does not affect the current directory in separate calls to `system()`.**

If you must use `system()`, then the best solution for you problem might be to avoid `cd` and just get everything done in one command. But this will only work if you can change `provaMake.txt`. In particular, this should work as the contents of `provaMake.txt`:

```bash
rm -f /home/giorgio/Desktop/a/pippo.txt
```

If you must use `system()` but can't or don't want to change `provaMake.txt`, or if you are specifically interested in how to use `system()` to run all the commands in a file *in the same shell process*, then you can pass `system()` a hard-coded command that starts a new shell and runs all the commands in that file in the same shell. For example, your C program could use the code:

```c
system(". /home/giorgio/Desktop/provaMake.txt");
```

**You would replace just about your entire program with that command.** No buffer is needed, because your C program is not itself reading from the file. Similarly, no `fopen()` call is needed. The shell is what opens, reads from, and executes commands from the file--this is the action of its `.` builtin, which is present when any Bourne-style shell is used. (`system()` uses `sh`, which is a Bourne-style shell, as is `bash`.)

Note that, if your C program subsequently relies on or otherwise observes its current working directory, that will still be unaffected by the `cd` commands run (just as in your original code) because they only ran in the shell.

---

It's sometimes reasonable to do things in a contrived manner, for learning purposes, so I don't want to tell you not to write a C program that uses `system()` to run all the shell commands from a file one by one. However, in the case where your actual goal is simply to run all the commands in a file, you don't need a C program. You can just use your shell:

- If you want to run the commands in your *current* shell process, so that its environment is affected--for example, so that the effects of `cd` commands persist afterwards--then you can just run:

  ```bash
  . /home/giorgio/Desktop/provaMake.txt
  ```
- If you want to run the commands in a *new* shell, so that the current shell's environment is not affected, then pass the name of the file as a command-line to the shell:

  ```bash
  bash /home/giorgio/Desktop/provaMake.txt
  ```

  You can adjust that command if the shell you are using, or want to use, is not bash. For example:

  ```bash
  sh /home/giorgio/Desktop/provaMake.txt
  ```
- You may want to make the list of commands itself be executable. To do that, add something like this to the beginning (adjust according to what shell should be used to interpret it):

  ```bash
  #!/bin/bash
  ```

  And change its permissions so that it is executable, by running the command:

  ```bash
  chmod +x filename
  ```

  Replace *`filename`* with the actual filename, such as `/home/giorgio/Desktop/provaMake.txt`.

  Then you can run the file like any program:

  ```
  ./provaMake.txt  # when you're in the directory that contains it
  ```

  ```bash
  /home/giorgio/Desktop/provaMake.txt  # from anywhere
  ```

In that last case especially, it is unusual to name the file with a `.txt` suffix. In general, it is common that files whose contents will be run with the `.` builtin are named with a `.sh` suffix, and that files that will be marked executable and run as scripts are named with no suffix. (The filename doesn't matter as far as the shell and operating system are concerned, though.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it was really what i was searching for

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it is not working for you, when I tried something similar it worked.

Anyway, adding a some `printf` statements can be very helpful to understand what a program is doing. For example, try adding this line inside your while-loop just in front of the `system` call:

```
printf("Now calling system() with buf = %s\n", buf);
```

Then compile and run again and look at the output, hopefully that should help you understand what is happening.